# calculate average rating in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, average

this is my table:

[image]

I want to fetch records of Those Vendor which contain ServiceDescription "Plaster" or Skills "Plaster" or
is in  Category "Plaster" and also want to calculate averagerating of those Vendor.

note:If there is no review Of any vendor then also that records should come.

this is my query:

```
select * from UserDetails u
  ,VendorInCategory v
  ,CategoryMaster c
  ,Review rv
where v.CategoryId=c.Id 
and u.Id=r.UserId 
and u.Id=rv.VendorId  
and v.VendorId=u.Id 
and ((u.ServiceDescription like '%Plaster%' ) 
or (u.Skills like '%Plaster%') 
or (c.Name like '%Plaster%'))
```

here problem in above query is i am not getting that vendor whose review is not there.

but i also want that vendor which does not contain review but matches my criteria.

**UserDetails:**

```
id     Servicedescription         Skills
1        Plaster                  plaster

2        construction             construvtion

3        plaster                  plaster

4        null                     null(not vendor)

5        null                     null(not vendor)
```

**Review**

```
id     CustomerId     Vendorid    rating

1       4                1          3

2       5                1          3
```

**Expected output:**

```
VendorId     ServiceDescription     Skills       averagerating

1              plaster              plaster           3

3              plaster              plaster           0
```

Note:final output should in descending order of average rating

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Would you mind giving us sample data and expected results.

Comment: i have posted the sample input and expected output please check it out.

Comment: can any body please provide me query i am badly struck on this

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6566/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this:

## SAMPLE DATA

```
create table UserDetails(
    Id int,
    ServiceDescription varchar(20),
    Skills varchar(20)
)
create table Review(
    Id int,
    CustomerId int,
    VendorId int,
    Rating int
)

insert into UserDetails values(1, 'Plaster', 'plaster'),(2, 'construction', 'construction'),(3, 'plaster', 'plaster');
insert into Review values(1, 4, 1, 3),(2, 5, 1, 3);
```

## SOLUTION

```
select
    u.Id as VendorId,
    u.ServiceDescription,
    u.Skills,
    isnull(sum(r.rating)/count(r.rating), 0) as AverageRating
from UserDetails u
left join Review r
    on r.VendorId = u.id
where
    u.ServiceDescription like '%plaster%'
    or u.Skills like '%plaster%'
group by 
    u.Id,
    u.ServiceDescription,
    u.Skills
order by AverageRating desc
```

Comment: You can replace `sum(s.rating)/count(r.rating)` with `avg(r.rating)`

Comment: thank u so much for helping me.thank u thank u so much and ya please keep helping like this.its because of people like you i always like to post my problem on stack overflow.

Comment: but what if i want to include all userDetails like fullname,Email etc..??

Comment: is it like if i want to include more details like fullname,email then i have to include all that field in my group by clause??

Comment: Correct. Just include additional columns in the group by clause

Comment: but dont u think thats appropriate because i want to include more than 10 columns in my select clause

Comment: @mariapithia It's ok.

Answer (score 3):

Many users have used the **AVERAGE** function to calculate the average of a series of data. But what do you do when you have summary data instead of individual responses and need to calculate an average? (For example, counts of the number of people who selected each rating on a 5-point rating scale like the rating of a product.)

**How to Calculate a Weighted Average**

Let’s say you want to get the average overall rating for each product:

- For rating 1, (9) nine people.
- For rating 2, (13) Thirteen people.
- For rating 3, (1) one people.

Using the AVERAGE function would result in an **average of 7.7**. Of course, this doesn’t make any sense. We should expect an average within the range of the scale (1 to 5).

In order to correctly calculate the average overall response to each question, we need to:

1. Multiply the number of individuals selecting each rating by the
   corresponding rating value (1 – 5)
2. Add the results of those calculations together.
3. Divide that result by the total number of responses to the question.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
create table #tableRatings(
    Id int,
    Rating numeric(18,6)
)

insert into #tableRatings values(1, 4.3),(2,3.3),(3,4.8);
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
    SELECT
    SUM(
    case 
        WHEN FLOOR(rating) = 1 THEN rating
        WHEN FLOOR(rating) = 2 THEN rating *2
        WHEN FLOOR(rating) = 3 THEN rating *3
        WHEN FLOOR(rating) = 4 THEN rating *4
        WHEN FLOOR(rating) = 5 THEN rating *5        
    end    
    ) / SUM(rating)
    FROM #tableRatings
```

**RESULT:**

```
3.733870
```

Comment: Hi, I have used the above query and it returns values rounded off to specific values, how to show decimal values with using above query

Comment: @OmBala make sure that the "rating" field type is numeric with decimals; the script doesn't change that, only multiply the value...

Answer (score -1):

Use aggregate function **AVG()**:

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.ServiceDescription, u.Skills, u.fullname, u.email, AVG(ISNULL(rv.rating, 0)) averagerating
FROM UserDetails u 
INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
LEFT JOIN Review rv ON u.Id=rv.VendorId  
WHERE (u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%Plaster%' OR u.Skills LIKE '%Plaster%' OR 
       c.Name LIKE '%Plaster%')
GROUP BY u.id, u.ServiceDescription, u.Skills, u.fullname, u.email
ORDER BY averagerating DESC;
```

**EDIT**

Other solution to implement this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.ServiceDescription, u.Skills, u.fullname, u.email, 
       ISNULL(rv.averagerating, 0) averagerating
FROM UserDetails u 
INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rv.VendorId, AVG(rv.rating) averagerating FROM Review rv GROUP BY rv.VendorId) rv ON u.Id=rv.VendorId  
WHERE (u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%Plaster%' OR u.Skills LIKE '%Plaster%' OR 
       c.Name LIKE '%Plaster%')
ORDER BY ISNULL(rv.averagerating, 0) DESC;
```

Comment: thank u so much for helping me.thank u thank u so much and ya please keep helping like this.its because of people like you i always like to post my problem on stack overflow.

Comment: @mariapithia Then you have to add those columns in select part and as well as in  Group by part if you are not using any aggregate functions on those columns

Comment: is it like if i want to include more details like fullname,email then i have to include all that field in my group by clause??

Comment: can u please edit ur query and just include that fields too because when i am including fullname then it is giving me error

Comment: but dont u think thats appropriate because i want to include more than 10 columns in my select clause

Comment: @mariapithia Yes, If we want any aggregation than we have to do this

Comment: but specifying evry field in group by clause which i am selecting in select clause wont make any difference naa?

Comment: @mariapithia no, it won't

Comment: @mariapithia Check my updated answer if you don't want to add every columns in group by clause then you can user inner query also

Comment: Damn good.thank u so much for sparing your valuable time for me and giving me solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66015/discussion-between-saharsh-shah-and-maria-pithia).