# fetch customer name who has given the review

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Please Refer to this Question which i have already ask:

[calculate average rating in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242641/calculate-average-rating-in-sql-server/27244014#27244014)

everything is working perfectly.I am also getting my desire output but i just want customer name who has given the review.

This is my query  which i have taken from above link:

```
 SELECT u.id,u.fullname,u.email,u.ServiceDescription, u.Skills,c.Name,rv.Reviews,
           ISNULL(rv.averagerating, 0) averagerating
    FROM UserDetails u 
    INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
    INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT rv.VendorId,rv.Reviews, AVG(rv.RatingValue) averagerating FROM Review rv GROUP BY rv.VendorId,rv.Reviews) rv ON u.Id=rv.VendorId  
    WHERE ((u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%SearchKeyword%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%@SearchKeyword%') OR 
           (c.Name LIKE '%@SearchKeyword%'))
    ORDER BY ISNULL(rv.averagerating, 0) DESC;
```

Now in that query it is possible to fetch Customer Name who has given the Review???

**UserDetails:**

```
id    Name       Servicedescription         Skills
1     john         Plaster                  plaster

2     abc          construction             construction

3     xyz          plaster                  plaster

4     pqr          null                     null(not vendor)

5     lmn          null                     null(not vendor)
```

**Review**

```
id     CustomerId     Vendorid    rating     reviews    

1       4                1          3         fdd

2       5                1          3         dfg
```

**Expected output:**

```
VendorId    ServiceDescription     Skills          rating   customername    reviews

1              plaster              plaster           3           pqr            good

3              plaster              plaster           3           lmn            bad
```

I dont want to calculate average rating.

can anybody please help me to do this????

Comment: How would u rate the riview is good or bad as in your review table the first record with rating 3 is riviews good but the second record with rating 3 is bad

Comment: reviews are already store in my review table

Comment: Do you want to calculate average rating or not

Answer (score 1):

Just make your `Left Join` between User Table and Review table as `Inner Join` and select the Name column from the User table

Try with the below Query

**Sample Data**

```
create table UserDetails(
    Id int,
    Name Varchar(250),
    ServiceDescription varchar(20),
    Skills varchar(20)
)
create table Review(
    Id int,
    CustomerId int,
    VendorId int,
    Rating int,
    review Varchar(25)
)

insert into UserDetails values(1, 'John','Plaster', 'plaster'),(2,'Paul', 'construction', 'construction'),(3,'AAA', 'plaster', 'plaster'),(4,'PQR',null,null),
(5,'lmn',null,null)
insert into Review values(1, 4, 1, 3,'Good'),(2, 5, 1, 0,'Bad');
```

**Query**

```
   select
    VendorId=r.CustomerId,
    vu.ServiceDescription,
    vu.Skills,
    AverageRating=r.rating,
    CustomerName=ru.Name,
    reviews=r.review
FROM Review r
JOIN UserDetails vu ON r.Vendorid = vu.id
JOIN UserDetails ru ON r.CustomerId = ru.id
where
    ru.ServiceDescription is null
    or ru.Skills is null
group by 
    r.CustomerId,
    ru.Name,
    vu.ServiceDescription,
    vu.Skills,r.rating,r.review
order by AverageRating desc
```

Comment: your customer name is coming wrong and you dont need to do any case for review.you just have to fetch reviews and rating associated with that review

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it exactly the way you want it, since averagerating is an average: what if ten different people reviewed that vendor? Whose name should it show?

You could, however, have a separate row for every review.

If that's what you want, try this.

EDIT: updated to include Review.reviews.

```
SELECT vu.id AS VendorId, vu.ServiceDescription, vu.Skills,
       r.RatingValue AS rating, ru.name AS customername, r.reviews
FROM Review r
JOIN UserDetails vu ON r.Vendorid = vu.id
JOIN UserDetails ru ON r.CustomerId = ru.id
```

Comment: forget about average rating.i dont want to calculate average rating

Comment: If you dont want to calculate Average rating why the same rating has both good and bad in your expected output

Comment: Where do the values "good" and "bad" come from here? Should it say "good" if the value is greater than 3 and "bad" otherwise? Or are "good" and "bad" text coming from `Review.reviews`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer I got I have prepared this query and expected output is coming:

```
SELECT u.id,u.fullname,u.email,u.ServiceDescription, 
u.Skills,c.Name,r.Reviews,r.RatingValue,ru.Id,
ru.Fullname FROM UserDetails u 
INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
left join Review r
    on r.VendorId = u.id
left JOIN UserDetails ru ON r.CustomerId = ru.id
WHERE ((u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%Plaster%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%Plaster%') OR 
       (c.Name LIKE '%Plaster%'))
ORDER BY ISNULL(r.RatingValue, 0) DESC;
```

now as you can see from below link my database design:

[calculate average rating in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242641/calculate-average-rating-in-sql-server/27244014#27244014)

[image]

here you can see plaster is subcategory of Construction(Id:40)

so i want to fetch parentcategory if any word i am searching in categorymaster is found.

if word is found in subcategory then fetch its parentcategory name else fetch parentcategory name only.

can anybody please edit my query to achieve this functionality???

Comment: Kindly Select the answer from which you got this idea as Accepted Answer or just Upvote it as a courtesy for spending their time to solve your issue

Comment: @Rajesh:so sorry i just forgot to upvote your ans.sorry once again