# fetch parent category name if searching word is found subcategory of category master

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to fetch parentcategory name.

```
SELECT u.id,u.fullname,u.email,u.ServiceDescription, 
u.Skills,c.Name,r.Reviews,r.RatingValue,ru.Id,
ru.Fullname FROM UserDetails u 
INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
left join Review r
    on r.VendorId = u.id
left JOIN UserDetails ru ON r.CustomerId = ru.id
WHERE ((u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%Plaster%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%Plaster%') OR 
       (c.Name LIKE '%Plaster%'))
ORDER BY ISNULL(r.RatingValue, 0) DESC;
```

now as you can see from below link my database design:

[calculate average rating in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242641/calculate-average-rating-in-sql-server/27244014#27244014)

[image]

here you can see plaster is subcategory of Construction(Id:40)

so i want to fetch parentcategory if any word i am searching for is found in categorymaster.

if word is found in subcategory then fetch its parentcategory name else fetch parentcategory name only.

can anybody please edit my query to achieve this functionality???

UserDetails:

id    Name       Servicedescription         Skills
1     john         Plaster                  plaster

2     abc          construction             construction

3     xyz          plaster                  plaster

4     pqr          null                     null(not vendor)

5     lmn          null                     null(not vendor)

Review

id     CustomerId     Vendorid    rating     reviews

1       4                1          3         fdd

2       5                1          3         dfg

Now if i am seraching for "Plaster"

then output should be:

VendorId    ServiceDescription    Skills    rating   customername    reviews ParentCategory

1              plaster            plaster       3           pqr        fdd    construction

3              plaster            plaster       3           lmn        dfg    Construction

here Construction(Id 40) is the ParentCategory of Plaster(Id 44) as u can see in image.if plaster does not have parentid then ParentCategory name should be plaster only.

Comment: Do U mean **if word is found in subcategory** as Parentid not null

Comment: means if i am seraching "Plaster" then plaster is subcategory of construction then i want construction

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT u.id,u.fullname,u.email,u.ServiceDescription, 
u.Skills,c.Name,r.Reviews,r.RatingValue,ru.Id,
ru.Fullname,ISNULL(c1.Name,c.Name) AS CategoryName FROM UserDetails u 
INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
LEFT JOIN CategoryMaster c1 ON c1.Id=c.ParentID
left join Review r
    on r.VendorId = u.id
left JOIN UserDetails ru ON r.CustomerId = ru.id
WHERE ((u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%Plaster%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%Plaster%') OR 
       (c.Name LIKE '%Plaster%'))
ORDER BY ISNULL(r.RatingValue, 0) DESC;
```

The below query will give parent:

```
SELECT c.Name AS Name,c1.Name As Parent FROM CategoryMaster c
LEFT JOIN CategoryMaster c1 on c1.ParentID=c.ID
```

Comment: Why cant we Left join the `CategoryMaster c1` with `CategoryMaster c` as `c1.ParentId==c.Id`

Comment: @mariapithia Please provide sample data

Answer (score -1):

Use Common table expression (CTE)

[Recursive CTE calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683011/How-to-use-recursive-CTE-calls-in-T-SQL)

**Sample User table structure**

```html
userId      userName         managerId
----------- ---------------- -----------
1           John             NULL
2           Charles          1
3           Nicolas          2
4           Neil             5
5           Lynn             1
6           Vince            5
7           Claire           6
```

In order to get all top level managers name we need to use CTE recursive call.

```html
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT userId, userName, managerId,0 AS steps
  FROM dbo.Users
  WHERE userId = 7

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.userId, mgr.userName, mgr.managerId, usr.steps +1 AS steps
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS mgr
      ON usr.managerId = mgr.userId
)
SELECT * FROM UserCTE AS u;
```

The above query will return all the managers name of userid = 7. Below is the output

```html
userId      userName         managerId   steps
----------- ---------------- ----------- -----------
7           Claire           6           0
6           Vince            5           1
5           Lynn             1           2
1           John             NULL        3
```

Comment: You may want to consider providing a brief explanation in addition to the link.

Comment: Try to add some details from the link you provided as when the link gets deleted it will throw 404 not found error  because it may be helpful to the OP